# Typescript generics or declare type on variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, web

I have just started to learn Typescript and there is one thing that I don’t understand.
What is the difference between:

(declaring the type of the variable)

```
function func1 (arg: any): any {
  return arg
}
let var1: string = func1(“Hello”)
```

And

(using generics)

```
function func2 <T>(arg: T): T {
  return arg
}
let var2 = func2<string>(“Hello”)
```

I have tried searching for similar quotations but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 2nd example with generics, the type is preserved if it is known at compile time.

For instance:

```
let x = 27; // x is a number
let y = func2(x); // y is inferred to be a number at compile time
```

`any` tells the TypeScript compiler that anything can be passed or returned from `func` - they won't have to match.

Comment: When writing code,  is the 2nd example the better practice? Or does it not have a difference if you use generics or not?

Comment: @LiamThorell that’s up to you. I generally try to avoid ‘any’ with typescript because it tells the compiler to ignore type safety